# jQuery serialize method won't work with input type file

Tags: jquery

I found this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com, it work great but I would like to do it without plugin. Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you mean you want to write that functionality from scratch?

Comment: What is the question? The title and the text doesn't correspond at all...

Comment: i mean: how to get serialize() works with input file

Comment: It doesnt make much sense to use `serialize` with a file input because you cant send the file in any other way than actually posting the form to the server... If you want to do ajax file submmission youll need to use the iframe or flash workarounds that exist. There should be some plugins for those, though i dont see any listed on Malsup's page.

Comment: @prodigitalson, data urls work well for that reason

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialise a file upload. The Javascript doesn't have access to the file data that would be uploaded.

The only way to do the upload (without using an applet/component) is to post the form where the file input is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can @Guffa ; I did.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://{url}/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
<script src="http://{url}/js/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#txtrform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtrform").submit(function(){

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#col3").load("/include/txtrpbox/feed.php");
            $('input#txtrinput').val('');
        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```